# iOS do I need to check for object equality when writing my own property setter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I'm reviewing some Apple code, and see that they have the equality check in the manually created property setter (see below). In my own code I frequently use just `_datasource = datasource;` Is there anything wrong with omitting the equality check? Are there any ARC implications, like double retain?

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray* datasource;

-(void)setDatasource:(NSArray *)datasource
{
//is there anything wrong if this test is missing?
    if(_datasource != datasource)
    {
        _datasource = datasource;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that is your entire setter method, there is no need to write it at all.

Comment: Typically I add a table view refresh or similar code at the end of this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your approach without doubt. ARC will automatically retain/release your underlying ivar(you declared it as strong). 
I think this check in Apple code remains from past version, which was under manual memory management.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with memory management. The only reason for this to be is that you might later want to add some additional functionality to your setter (this is the purpose of custom setter, after all) and it is often good if this code is invoked only once for a particular object.

Answer (score 0):

The programmer is checking if someone is trying to assign the very same object as a value. If they do the assignment will not happen which suppose to make your code more efficient.